# List sale orders with deposit paid

Tags: odoo

I would like to have a filter on sale orders that allow me to show sale order that had an deposit invoice paid.

How could I make this ?

Here is what I began to write :

- For the filter :

`<filter string="Sale order with deposit paid" domain="[('partially_invoiced','=',True),(invoiced','=',False)]"/>`

- for the sale.order model :

class sale(osv.osv):

```
_inherit = 'sale.order'     
_columns = {
        'partially_invoiced': fields.function(.....),
                }
```

I don't know how to do for the python function that should retrieve the appropriate sale orders.

Thank for your help

Victor

Answer (score 0):

you should add your filter to a search record. this is an example how

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="course_search_view">
        <field name="name">course.search</field>
        <field name="model">openacademy.course</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search>
                <field name="name" />
                <field name="description" />
                <filter name="my_courses" string="My Courses"
                    domain="[('responsible_id', '=', uid)]" />
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>
```

hope that help.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this. My problem is more about implementing the python code to retrieve the appropriate sale orders...